# Google Cloud Bigtable: Storing multiple rows for a row key

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

In Bigtable, I am trying to create a column family corresponding to a row key in this format shown below.

[image]

Under the preferences column, there are multiple cells. Note that these are not multiple versions of the same cell, but multiple cells in a column corresponding to same row key.

Access patterns include:

- reading all the preferences of user(RK)
- reading the beta preference of a user
  and so on.

How do I create a column family in this schema?

Answer (score 5):

The most straightforward option is to create a column family called "preferences" with columns named "alpha", "beta", "gamma", etc. This structure is compatible with both reading all preferences (just read all columns) or a single preference (use a column filter).